# Why the space of section of a vector bundle is complete?

Tags: vector-bundles, complete-spaces, connections, locally-convex-spaces

This page is about the  [space of sections](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/space+of+sections):

> Let $E \stackrel{\mathrm{fb}}{\rightarrow} \Sigma$ be a smooth vector bundle.  On its real vector space $\Gamma_{\Sigma}(E)$ of smooth sections consider the seminorms indexed by a compact subset $K \subset \Sigma$ and a natural number $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and given by
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \Gamma_{\Sigma}(E) & \stackrel{p_{K}^{N}}{\longrightarrow} [0,\infty)\\
> \Phi & \longmapsto \max _{n \leq N}\left(\sup _{x \in K}\left|\left(\nabla^{E}\right)^{n} \Phi(x)\right|\right)
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> where on the right we have the absolute values of the covariant derivatives of $\Phi$ for any fixed choice of connection on $E$ and norm on the tensor product of vector bundles $\left(T^{*} \Sigma\right)^{\otimes_{\Sigma}^{n}} \otimes_{\Sigma} E$.

Let $(U, \varphi, \rho)$ be a total trivialization triple for $E$.and  $u \in \Gamma_{U}(E)$. On  $U$  we may write  $u=u^{a} s_{a}$

Now in general we have  $$\left(\nabla^{E}\right)^{k} 
u=\left(\left(\nabla^{E}\right)^{k} u\right)_{i_{1} \ldots i_{1}}^{a} d x^{i_{1}} \otimes \cdots \otimes d x^{i_{k}} \otimes s_{a}$$

where $$\left(\left(\nabla^{E}\right)^{k} u\right)_{i_{1} \cdots i_{k}}^{a} \circ \varphi^{-1}=\frac{\partial ^k}{\partial x^{i_{1}} \ldots \partial x^{i_{k}}}\left(u^{a} \circ \varphi^{-1}\right)+\sum_{\underline{n} \mid<k_{l}} \sum_{l=1} C_{\eta l} \partial^{\eta}\left(u^{l} \circ \varphi^{-1}\right)$$

where for each $\eta$ and $l, C_{\eta l}$ is a polynomial in terms of Christoffel symbols (of the linear connection on $M$ and connection in $E$ ).

Now suppose we have a metric $g$ in $U$ and a metric $h$ in $E$ then we have that
$$\left|\left(\nabla^{E}\right)^{n} u\right|= \left(\left(\nabla^{E}\right)^{k} u\right)_{i_{1} \cdots i_{k}}^{a}\left(\left(\nabla^{E}\right)^{k} u\right)_{j_{1} \cdots j_{k}}^{b} g^{i_1 j_i}\cdots g^{i_k j_k}h^{ab}$$
How to prove that this space is complete in respect to the seminorm?

Now In this  article on page 6 [GREEN-HYPERBOLIC OPERATORS ON GLOBALLY HYPERBOLIC SPACETIMES](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.0738) the author says that an Arzelà-Ascoli argument would show this but I don't see how.

If anyone would like me to  expand the question please let me know.

Comment: Just checking: Are you happy with the corresponding statement for real-valued functions on an open subset of a Cartesian space, i.e., uniform convergence on compacta of the derivatives up to order $N$ (assuming terms of the sequence are $N$ times continuously differentiable) implies the limit exists and is $N$ times continuously differentiable?

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang yes I know how to proof that

Comment: Thank you; I was trying to gauge whether the issue was "analytical" or "geometric". The point here will be to work in a trivializing neighborhood, and to express the connection and norm in terms of vector-valued functions on open sets in Cartesian space. Writing the details may be a bit fussy; I'm hoping someone (else) will do so. :)